# publish() to a closed topic when publishing a marker

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys! I am trying to subscribe a message (/position) and publish a marker.
The message(/position) contains series of (x,y,z) as below :

```
...
---
x: -253.021528805
y: -545.031320081
z: -465.328910428   
---
x: -305.591390007
y: -578.07464085
z: -511.685201552
---
...
```

Below is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Vector3
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker


def callback(position):
  marker_pub = rospy.Publisher('route', Marker, queue_size = 100)

  while not rospy.is_shutdown() :
    # print(pos_vec)
    marker = Marker()
    marker.header.frame_id = '/map'
    marker.type = marker.LINE_STRIP
    marker.action = marker.ADD

    #Marker scale
    marker.scale.x = 0.1
    marker.scale.y = 0.1
    marker.scale.z = 0.1

    #Marker color
    marker.color.a = 1.0
    marker.color.r = 1.0
    marker.color.g = 1.0
    marker.color.b = 0.0

    #Marker orientation
    marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
    marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
    marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
    marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

    #Marker line points
    marker.points = []
    p = Point()
    p.x = position.x
    p.y = position.y
    p.z = position.z
    marker.points.append(p)

    #Publish the marker
    marker_pub.publish(marker)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
rospy.init_node("marker_publisher")
rospy.Subscriber("/position", Vector3, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

However, I got the following errors :

```
[ERROR] [1521469185.321377]: bad callback: <function draw at 0x7f184ad9cb18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/home/parallels/SDC_ws/src/simon/src/marker.py", line 45, in draw
marker_pub.publish(marker)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 882, in publish
self.impl.publish(data)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1041, in publish
raise ROSException("publish() to a closed topic")
ROSException: publish() to a closed topic
```

I have searched the Internet but it seems very few people had encountered this kind of problem.
Can anyone give me some hint? Thank you!
Sorry for any grammar mistakes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285869/publish()-to-a-closed-topic-when-publishing-a-marker/) by [arthur0304](https://answers.ros.org/users/34220/arthur0304/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:
This is probably not the answer, but please add a `rospy.sleep(1.0)` (or some similar period) to your `while not rospy.is_shutdown()` loop. Right now you're unnecessarily burning through 100% of your cpu cycles while publishing `Marker` msgs as fast as possible.

**Comment by [arthur0304](https://answers.ros.org/users/34220/arthur0304/) on 2018-03-19**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for your advice! You mean to change the *Publisher to the main function in this case? Is that what you mean?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-19**:
Create all your `Publisher` and `Subscriber` objects in your main, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On second thought: *never* add an infinite `while`-loop to a callback body. *Ever*.

Callbacks must never block (infinitely).

Also: don't create `Publisher`s in callbacks. Do that in the initialisation phase/section of your program.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arthur0304](https://answers.ros.org/users/34220/arthur0304/) on 2018-03-20**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you! I have solved the problem. Indeed the while loop should not be infinite.

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-05**:
@arthur0304  Please explain how you solved your problem, not just mentioning it.